# Mongodb accessing documents

Tags: mongodb

I've the following db:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "results" : [ { "product" : "abc", "score" : 10 }, { "product" : "xyz", "score" : 5 } ] }
{ "_id" : 2, "results" : [ { "product" : "abc", "score" : 8 }, { "product" : "xyz", "score" : 7 } ] }
{ "_id" : 3, "results" : [ { "product" : "abc", "score" : 7 }, { "product" : "xyz", "score" : 8 } ] }
```

I want to show the first score of each _id, i tried the following:

```
db.students.find({},{"results.$":1})
```

But it doesn't seem to work, any advice?

Answer (score 0):

You can take advantage of [aggregation pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) to solve this.

Use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) in conjunction with [$arrayElemAt](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) to point to appropriate node index in the array.

So, to extract the documents of the first score, have written below query.

```
db.students.aggregate([ {$project: { scoredoc:{$arrayElemAt:["$results",0]}} } ]);
```

In case if you just wish to have scores excluding product, use `$results.score` as shown below.

```
db.students.aggregate([ {$project: { scoredoc:{$arrayElemAt:["$results.score",0]}} } ]);
```

Here `scoredoc` object will have all documents of first score element.

Hope this helps!

Comment: And putting `"$results.score"` as the argument to `$arrayElemAt` will return only the value of the score property.

Comment: @NeilLunn, have added now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to above mentioned description please try executing following query in MongoDB shell

```
db.students.find(
 {results:
  {$elemMatch:{score:{$exists:true}}}}, {'results.$.score':1}
)
```

According to MongoDB documentation

> The positional $ operator limits the contents of an  from the
>   query results to contain only the first element matching the query
>   document.

Hence in above mentioned query **positional $ operator** is used in projection section to retrieve first score of each document.